# Graph misordering X axis in R

Tags: r

I'm working on making a graph for my thesis in R of different blocks of trials. 10 is for some reason coming after 1 thinking it's in order.

The code I currently have is

```
library(dplyr)
All1 <- mydata[,c(36:45,98)]

meansall1 <- aggregate(All1[, 1:(ncol(All1)-1)], list(All1$Group), mean)
tmeansall1 <- data.frame(t(meansall1))
names(tmeansall1) <- c("AN", "HC")
meanstall1 <- tmeansall1[-1,]
meanstall1$trials <- rownames(meanstall1)

library(reshape2)
meltall1<- melt(meanstall1, id = "trials")

ggplot(data = meltall1, aes(trials, value, group=variable)) + geom_line(aes(linetype=variable))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: That is alphabetical order

Comment: If for some reason my answer below doesn't solve your problem, please post a subset of your data that will reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The graph is not ordering anything. It's already ordered in `meltall1`.  If you want to re-order it before passing it to `ggplot`, see the example below:

`arrange()` is the `dplyr` function for ordering rows according to a column. Here you don't just want to order it according to a column (because it's already in that order):

```
arrange(df, x)
#       x           y
# 1  Xab1 -0.06191171
# 2 Xab10  0.82158108
# 3  Xab2  0.55391765
# 4  Xab3  0.68864025
```

You want to order it according to a transformation of that column:

```
arrange(df, as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", x)))
#       x           y
# 1  Xab1 -0.06191171
# 2  Xab2  0.55391765
# 3  Xab3  0.68864025
# 4 Xab10  0.82158108
```

The idiom here: `as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", x))`produces a vector that will order as you might expect a character vector with one number in it to order.  If you want to use it with base R odering instead of dplyr ordering you'd do:

```
df[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df$x))),]
#       x          y
# 3  Xab1 0.12928774
# 1  Xab2 1.55870831
# 2  Xab3 0.07050839
# 4 Xab10 1.71506499
```

The only difference here is that the row numbers generated in the original call to `data.frame` are retained.

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- c("Xab1", "Xab2", "Xab3", "Xab10")
df <- data.frame(x = sample(x), y = rnorm(4))
#       x          y
# 1  Xab2 1.55870831
# 2  Xab3 0.07050839
# 3  Xab1 0.12928774
# 4 Xab10 1.71506499
```

Comment: Perhaps OP is after something like `meanstall1 %>%
  mutate(x = fct_reorder(trials, as.numeric(str_extract_all(trials, "[0-9]+")))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = trials, y = value, group = variable)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = variable))`